# How to open the channel and push the data into while loop?

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to traverse the `ls | grep` command in to the channel, which is while looping and pushing the output to the `@output` array. But, while loop is not providing the necessary output because of which the code will die with `die "could not find the file $_[1] in $Source to $Destination \n" unless(@output);`. If I comment the die part of the code and proceed with the copy from source to destination is not working.

Here is part of my code:

```
    my $host ="$hash{Linux_Server_IP}";
    my $Uname = "$hash{Linux_Server_Username}";
    my $password ="$hash{Linux_Server_Password}";
    my $ssh2= Net::SSH2->new();

    $ssh2->connect($host)or die "Could not connect : $@ \n ";
    $ssh2->auth_password($Uname,$password) or die "Could not login : Reason : $@\n";
    $ssh2->blocking();
    our $chnl = $ssh2->channel();
    $chnl->shell();

print $chnl "ls | grep $_[1] \n";
my @output;
sleep(1);
while (<$chnl>){push @output,$_};
die "could not find the file $_[1] in $Source to $Destination \n" unless(@output);
print $chnl "cp $Source $Destination \n";
```

Error in the log:

> could not find the file ABC.csv in /data/Directory1/ABC.csv to /data/Directory2/ABC.csv

I manually verified the file on the server and it does exist. Please advise.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense: the first line _prints to_ `$chnl` filehandle, but in the `while` condition you _read from_ it, with `<>`. Also, you seem to be printing ... text of commands? (And why is all this under backticks?)  Can you post a short program that actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I guess `$chnl` is an SSH channel to a remote shell session? You should [edit] your question to show how you open this channel in the first place and any other commands which you run through it prior to this.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @kenster : I am opening the channel but i am not able to get the ouput traversed through the while loop.

Comment: What does `print $chnl "ls | grep $_[1] \n";` do? Where is that documented?

Comment: @zdim : I have removed the backticks. The question here is i am not able to see the output get pushed in to output variable. Is there any other way which we can use to get the things done?

Comment: @melpomene : $_[1] is an input which contains ABC.csv file. It will grep and find the file. I am expecting that filename to be pushed to the $chnl  and that will be traversed through while loop and pushed  in to output variable.But,  i am not able to get the data in to output variable.

Comment: So it appears  printing to `$chnl` sends commands to be executed?  (The `Net::SSH2::Channel` docs don't really say much.)  If that is the case, `grep filename` isn't much of a command, and it actually shouldn't even return, for a while at least.  Can you explain what you are trying to do with `ls | grep filename`?  (I take it from your comments above that `$_[1]` is a filename)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Net::SSH2::Channel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2::Channel#process-(-request,-message-))

> Alternatively, it is also possible to launch a remote shell (using
>   shell) and simulate the user interaction printing commands to its
>   stdin stream and reading data back from its stdout and stderr. But
>   this approach should be avoided if possible; talking to a shell is
>   difficult and, in general, unreliable.

Furthermore using `ls` to detect if a file/directory exists is fragile and unreliable. You should use file test operations instead, e.g.

```perl
sub exec_remote($$) {
    my($ssh2, $cmd) = @_;

    # every exec() requires a new channel
    my $chan = $ssh2->channel()
        or $ssh2->die_with_error;

    # send command to remote
    $chan->exec($cmd)
        or $ssh2->die_with_error;

    # we're done from our side
    $chan->send_eof;

    # ignore command output
    while (<$chan>) {}

    # wait for remote command to complete and return its exit status
    return $chan->exit_status;
}

sub copy_remote_if_necessary($$$$) {
     my($ssh2, $source, $destination, $file) = @_;

     if (exec_remote($ssh2, "/usr/bin/test -f ${destination}/${file}") ne 0) {
         die "Copy failed!\n"
             unless (exec_remote($ssh2, "cp ${source}/${file} ${destination}/") ne 0);
     }
}

copy_remote_if_necessary($ssh2, '/data/Directory1', '/data/Directory2', 'ABC.csv');
```